# time varying continuous covariate with one single binary outcome

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, time-varying-covariate

Despite having only a single binary outcome for each ID, there are multiple correlated measurements for the same test for each ID at different timepoints. The individual ID´s are obviously independent, but the measurements of the same test at different time-points are not independent. The aim is to see whether the test can discern if the patients is cured or not.

-I cannot decide whether I´d need to fit a mixed-level logistic regression model or if a regular logistic regression model would suffice. Is it possible somehow to fit a logistic regression model with time varying covariates like in cox models?

-Is it possible to use a clustering or CART based model (allowing for the longitudinal independent variable) instead that would be easier to comprehend in a clinical setting?

-I could turn the question around and do repeated measure Anova with `summary(aov(val~Long_term*time+Error(id),data=stat))`- however, 1)only time and the interaction term are significant, leaving me uncertain how to treat the other main effect of Long_term in face of only a significant interaction and 2)it feels contraintuitive to set an independent variable as a dependent variable when using anova.

```
> dput(stat)
structure(list(Long_term = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No",  "Yes"), class = "factor"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,  8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L,  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,  16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,  11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L,  19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,  14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,  9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L,  3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L,  17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,  7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L,  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,  15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,  10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L,  18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L,  13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,  8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L,  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,  16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,  11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L,  19L), time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,  18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,  24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 30, 30, 30, 30,  30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 36,  36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36,  36, 36, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,  42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48,  48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54,  54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60,  60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 66, 66,  66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66,  66, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72,  72, 72, 72, 72, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78,  78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84,  84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,  90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 96, 96, 96,  96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96,  102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102,  102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102), val = c(273, 194, 618, 755, 802,  395, 2438, 482, 502, 692, 607, 618, 579, 864, 579, 453, 673,  572, 707, 57, 373, 1197, 1026, NA, 697, 712, NA, NA, 616, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76, 1128, 560, 76, 819, 982, 303, 1294,  267, 1117, 346, 996, 652, 95, 951, 3250, 1584, 948, 981, 465,  411, 57, 197, 535, 498, 87, 1382, 210, 1649, 96, 450, 252, 42,  1086, 2137, 1395, 464, 1388, 532, 67, 25, 230, 566, 545, 38,  691, 216, 1412, 33, 151, 113, 29, 663, 806, 528, 240, 1508, 421,  50, 39, NA, 182, 412, 32, 414, 232, 868, 791, 201, 86, 33, 250,  345, 224, 381, 1069, 536, NA, NA, NA, 500, 312, NA, 287, 97,  227, 653, 69, 69, NA, NA, 225, 308, 256, 963, 420, NA, NA, NA,  368, 605, NA, 399, 69, 77, 20, 39, 70, NA, 122, 306, 103, 175,  807, 530, NA, NA, NA, 246, 443, NA, 363, 87, 39, NA, 25, 63,  NA, 163, 289, 172, 128, 1019, 582, NA, NA, NA, 231, 820, NA,  284, NA, 40, NA, NA, NA, NA, 238, 288, 217, NA, 903, 471, NA,  NA, NA, 236, 577, NA, 461, NA, 691, NA, NA, NA, NA, 158, 170,  168, NA, 681, 434, NA, NA, NA, 399, 634, NA, 85, NA, 83, NA,  NA, NA, NA, 72, 419, NA, NA, 912, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 635, NA,  295, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, 138, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 251, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 132,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA,  -323L), .Names = c("Long_term", "id", "time", "val"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I've dealt with similar data in the past and wondered the same thing. Ultimatly I ended up using a logistic regression as I couldn't get a mixed-model to work. I could be wrong, but I figured there was not enough individual level variation to hyparameterize the main effect.

Comment: You need to clearly specify your data. What is the meaning of *long_term*. How many categories does it have? Is there any nested structure in your data? etc.

Comment: Long_term is a binary variable for cure-yes/no. The Val variable is a continuous variable measured on multiple occasions nested within id- but long before the outcome is measured.